# Logging and monitoring on front end SPA application

Tags: reactjs, logging, frontend, single-page-application

is there any logging and monitoring best practices for React SPA around? (library, the benefit etc.) I've been doing FE ~7years but shame, I don't have much experiences with it.

My experiences is that the incident that happens on Frontend app is very obvious and easy to track on the browser. So implementing logging or monitoring is not so useful as on Backend.

Answer (score 3):

I think that utilising some external library would be your best bet.

First of all, implementing an [Error Boundary](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html) to catch and handle all the errors in your react app would be the cleanest solution. After the boundary catches such an error, then depending on your needs you could handle each type of errors in a certain way.

There are plenty of external logging services that you could use to store and manage selected errors:

- [Sentry](https://sentry.io/for/react/) - which is my default pick
- [LogRocket](https://logrocket.com/for/react/)
- [Rollbar](https://rollbar.com/error-tracking/react/)

To name a few.

Comment: Sentry is for error logging, not generic logging.